# Processing collection in sets

Tags: c#, linq

I've a C# generics list collection of customer `Ids[customerIdsList]`.Lets say its count is 25.

I need to pass these Ids in sets of 10[a value which would be configurable and read from app.config]
to another method `ProcessCustomerIds()` which would process this customer Ids one by one.
ie. the first iteration will pass 10,next will pass the next 10 customer Ids and the last one will pass 5 Ids...and so on and so forth...

How do I achieve this using Linq?
Shall I be using Math.DivRem to do this?

```
int result=0;
int quotient = Math.DivRem(customerIdsList.Count, 10, out result)
Output:
quotient=2
result=5
```

So, I will iterate customerIdsList 2 times and invoke `ProcessCustomerIds()` in each step.

And if result value is greater than 0,then I will do customerIdsList.Skip(25-result) to get the last 5 customerIds from the collection.
Is there any other cleaner, more efficient way to do this? Please advise.

Comment: Why? What does doing it in blocks of 10 (or N) give you?

Comment: The ProcessCustomerIds() is a call over http on a third party server and is typically very process intensive.Hence, I want to do processing in chunks rather than making a new call for each customer Id.

Comment: I still don't see the benefit. If you call the server in chunks you're still processing all of the elements in series on after another. The server would be just as busy if you processed in chunks, one-by-one, or all at once. Or is it that you are trying to get results back to the user more quickly?

Comment: @Enigmativity, presumably, the overhead and latency of network communication makes a difference here. So making fewer requests is worth it. And maybe the server has a limit of how many items can be processed at once? I've encountered similar situation few times before.

Comment: @Enigmativity,Yes,the users need to see the results faster in the app.Also, if I send requests to the third party in sets,then I get to exploit caching mechanism implemented on their server using which more than 1 id can be processed in one single request much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our project, we have an extension method "Slice" which does exactly what you ask.  It looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Slice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int size)
{
    var slice = new List<T>();
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        slice.Add(item);
        if (slice.Count >= size)
        {
            yield return slice;
            slice = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if (slice.Count > 0) yield return slice;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
customerIdsList.Slice(10).ToList().ForEach(ProcessCustomerIds);
```

An important feature of this implementation is that it supports deferred execution.  (Contrary to an approach using GroupBy).  Granted, this doesn't matter most of the time, but sometimes it does.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use this to group the collection:

```
var n = 10;
var groups = customerIdsList
    .Select((id, index) => new { id, index = index / n })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index);
```

Then just run through the groups and issue the members of the group to the server one group at a time.

Comment: +1 for Using existing extension methods like they were intended rather than dreaming up your own custom behavior for very specific scenarios.

Comment: What I don't like about this solution (as opposed to Geert's) is that it always copies the whole collection into a temporary hash table. That means it uses unnecessarily too much memory and that it's unusable for infinite collections. Of course, such things don't always matter.

Comment: @svick - Good point. This approach isn't the best if you have large collections and obviously impossible on infinite collections. That's where I would look at the "Ix" (interactive extensions) from the Reactive Extensions team at Microsoft. They have produced all sorts of very useful extensions such as `Buffer` which would solve this problem nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Skip` and `Take` methods.

For example:

```
List <MyObject> list = ...;
int pageSize = 10;
int pageNumber = list.Count / pageSize;
for (int i =0; i<pageNumber; i++){
   int currentItem = i * pageSize;
   var query = (from obj in list orderby obj.Id).Skip(currentItem).Take(pageSize);
   // call method
}
```

Remember to order the list if you want to use `Skip` and `Take` .

Comment: This will work well only if the collection implements `IList<T>`. If not, it will iterate over the collection over and over again, resulting in O(N^2) time complexity. And for some collections, you can't iterate over them multiple times at all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunks<T>(this List<T> source, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += size)
        {
            yield return i - source.Count > size
                            ? source.Skip(i)
                            : source.Skip(i).Take(size);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var chunks = customerIdsList.Chunks(10);

foreach(var c in chunks)
{
    ProcessCustomerIds(c);
}
```